# Many callback in InstanceContextMode.Single

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0, callback, wsdualhttpbinding

I have service `InstanceContextMode` sets to `Single` mode.

I'm connecting with many clients to this service, getting it's callback channel with `OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMyService>()` and tring to send some message to each connected client, but I get the same message twice in only one client (this one which was conneceted later)

If I have `InstanceContexMode` `PerSession` everything works great.

What did I missed? Because be default I suppose it is possible, right?

Answer (score 0):

WSDualHttpBinding (aka "duplex" binding) requires session to work correctly. The session is used to keep track of the callback channel on a per-client basis, IIRC.